# comparing sprites in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

This is my code:

```
    private Sprite sprGuy;

    sprGuy  = atlas.createSprite("guy");

    Sprite a = new Sprite(sprGuy);
    Sprite b = new Sprite(sprGuy);

    if (a.equals(b)) {
        System.out.println("a is equal to b");
    }
```

According to Libgdx documentation:  *new Sprite(Sprite sprite)*... "Creates a sprite that is a **copy in every way** of the specified sprite."

But if **'a'** is a copy of *sprGuy* and **'b'** is a copy of *sprGuy*, why **a.equals(b)** is false?

How should I check if sprites are from the same "father"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my new approach:

First, I created this new class:

```
public class SpriteAux {

    public String name;
    public Sprite sprite;

    public SpriteAux(Sprite sprite, String name) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.name = name;       
    }

}
```

So, creating new objects containing sprite and name, we can get and compare the names:

```
private Sprite sprGuy;
private Sprite sprBoss;

sprGuy  = atlas.createSprite("guy");
sprBoss  = atlas.createSprite("boss");

SpriteAux a = new SpriteAux(sprGuy, "guy");
SpriteAux b = new SpriteAux(sprGuy, "guy");
SpriteAux c = new SpriteAux(sprBoss, "boss");

if (a.name.equals(b.name)) {                  //This is true!
    System.out.println("a is equal to b");
}

if (a.name.equals(c.name)) {                  //This is false!
    System.out.println("a is equal to c");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the libGDX [Sprite.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java) source file, the `equals()` method hasn't been implemented for `Sprite`.

So you're calling the default `equals()` method of the Java `Object` class which just compares the references, which are different for the two objects in your code.

Answer (score 1):

if it is for something simple and have control over the assignment of texture in the sprite, you can use this example:

```
private Sprite sprGuy;

sprGuy  = atlas.createSprite("guy");

Sprite a = new Sprite(sprGuy);
Sprite b = new Sprite(sprGuy);

if (a.getTexture().equals(b.getTexture())) {
    System.out.println("a is equal to b");
}
```